# Is the cap product bilinear?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

This is probably a stupid question, so I apologize in advance.

On  p. 239 of Hatcher's book, he defines the cap product $C_k(X;R)\times C^l(X;R)\to C_{k-l}(X;R)$ for $k\geq l$, which he claims is $R$-bilinear, by the formula:
$$
\sigma\frown\phi=\phi(\sigma([v_0\dots v_l])\sigma([v_l\dots v_k]).
$$
I can see that this is $R$-linear on the cochains, but why does 
$$
(\sigma_1+\sigma_2)\frown \phi=\sigma_1\frown \phi+\sigma_2\frown \phi?
$$

Is he $\textit{declaring}$ that it should be bilinear by using the last equation to extend the definition to all of $C_k(X;R)$?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is linear extension. In more detail, for every cochain $\psi$ we have a *map* from $k$-simplices $\sigma$ to $k-l$ chains, and then extend this map to a *homomorphism* on the free abelian group on the $k$-simplices, i.e. the $k$-chains. So this is just the definining universal property of the free abelian group. These kind of definitions are abundant. However, please take a look at the FAQ of MO; you will find out that these "elementary" questions do not fit here.

Comment: math.stackechange.com would be a fine place to ask this, though!